# How to sync premissions with chanels parent

Tags: discord, discord.js

I need to sync premissions with chanel parrent, but I have no idea how to do it. (I am using discord.js) I already have code, that parent it, so I only need to sync premisions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To synchronize a channel permission with the permissions of its parent, you need to use `channel#lockPermissions()`. For example:

```js
let channel = bot.channels.get('channel_id');
channel.lockPermissions();
// channel has the same permissions as its parent
```

Comment: i tried it, but it did nothing
`chanel.setParent(message.guild.channels.find(c => c.name == "feature requests" && c.type == "category").id).then(chanel2=>{
          //console.log(chanel2.parent)
          chanel2.lockPermissions();
        })`

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by this code

```
const permissionOverwrites = chanel2.parent.permissionOverwrites.map(overwrite => ({
  deny: overwrite.deny,
  allow: overwrite.allow,
  id: overwrite.id,
  type: overwrite.type,
}));
chanel2.replacePermissionOverwrites({overwrites: permissionOverwrites})
```